# How to pass parameter values to maven gzip ant task?

Tags: ant, maven, parameters, gzip

Gzip can take parameters, as described [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gzip). I would like to gzip some files from maven using [ant-run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html), but the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pack.html) does not explain how to pass parameters.

Is this possible, and if yes, how to proceed?

Comment: Do you want to use the ant task gzip or the external utility gzip?

Comment: @FailedDev As long as I can pass parameters (such as compression level for example), it does not matter if I can use it from maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ant gzip task does not provide the necessary attributes for you to pass your arguments, you shall use the exec task :

```
<target name="runGZip">
  <exec executable="gzip">
    <arg value="bla"/>
    ....
  </exec>
</target>
```

In addition to this, since you want portability you should use conditional execution depending on the os. If you need more help let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The [gzip (pack) task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pack.html) does not have any parameters except the source and destination file. A workaround to pass compression level to gzip is using the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and running gzip as a system command but it's not a portable solution.

Don't forget that Ant is open source. The [Gzip task](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Build/ANT-1.8/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/GZip.java.htm) uses JDK's [`GZIPOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html). It still doesn't have any method to set the compression level but it's possible to [create a `GZIPOutputStream` subclass](http://www.redirecttonull.com/?p=134) which supports this. After that you can create a custom gzip task (based on the original code) which uses the subclassed `GZIPOutputStream` instead of `GZIPOutputStream`. The task can pass the compression level setting from the Ant XML to the stream.